# Infinite sum of (root test is not useful) series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The root test of this example $\sum \left ( 1- \frac {1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) ^n$ is not so useful. How can I show this series converges/diverges?

Comment: Compare it with the series $\sum_n e^{-\sqrt{n}}$. And this one with one of the convergent harmonic, like $\sum_n 1/n^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\log\big(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\big)^n=n\log\big(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\big)=-\sqrt{n}+o(1)$$
And the series $$\sum_{n\ge 1}{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}$$ is convergent.

Comment: Can I approximate only one term?

Comment: The first approximation suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n \implies \log(a_n)=n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$
Now, for large values of $n$, use Taylor expansion to get
$$\log(a_n)=-\sqrt n -\frac 12-\frac 1{4n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which means that $$a_n < e^{-\sqrt n -\frac 12} <e^{-\sqrt n}$$